# conda install stuck at Solving environment: / warning libmamba Added empty dependency for problem type SOLVER_RULE_UPDATE

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

Trying to install gym using conda install -c conda-forge gym but the installer is stuck in

```
Solving environment: / warning libmamba Added empty dependency for problem type SOLVER_RULE_UPDATE
```

anyone experienced this before

I tried updating conda and adding and removing the channel conda-forge but still have the issue

Comment: Are you trying to install into an Anaconda **base** environment? Anaconda **base** is for most practical purposes incompatible with Conda Forge. If you need a Conda Forge package, then create a new environment that prioritizes `conda-forge` channel.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I tried both in base and in a conda environment, facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck trying to install `pytorch` on mac:

```
conda install pytorch-nightly::pytorch torchvision torchaudio -c pytorch-nightly
```

And `Conda` couldn't finish the task at hand.

I managed to get it done by configuring conda to use their previous dependency solver:

```
conda config --set solver classic
```